# How to access value of object in java script

Tags: javascript

how to access values of following object in java script?

```
$scope.filterView = {
 "priority": {
    "oldVal": "",
    "newVal": ""
 },
 "task": {
    "oldVal": "",
    "newVal": ""
 },
 "status": {
    "oldVal": "",
    "newVal": ""
 },
 "client": {
    "oldVal": "",
    "newVal": ""
 },
 "deal": {
    "oldVal": "",
    "newVal": ""
 }
};
```

Comment: Hi Deepali what do you want to access, please detail.

Comment: It seems that you lack even very basic knowledge of JavaScript. Stack Overflow is **not** a site where we teach you language basics. You have to learn something yourself first and come back only when you have **specific** problems, not overly general questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a specific key:

```
$scope.filterView.priority // returns {"oldVal": "", "newVal": ""}
$scope.filterView.priority.oldVal // returns ""
```

If you want to iterate:

```
for(var key in $scope.filterView) console.log($scope.filterView[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(key in $scope.filterView) {
    if($scope.filterView.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = $scope.filterView[key];
        //do something with value;
    }
}
```